# Is there a way to redirect to a component using an external link within an office-js application in excel?

Tags: angular, excel, office-js

I'm building an office-js application using Angular and Firebase, the app will be sideloaded in Excel.

I'm trying to create a "Forgot password" feature. Once a user clicks on "Forgot Password" button, a link will be sent to his email that redirect to "localhost.../action". Clicking or pasting the link in the browser does not work because the application is sideloaded in excel and cannot be opened as a normal web page.

Is there a workaround to this ? How can I implement this feature or make it work in some way ?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is supposed to happen on the /action route? The possible solutions might depend on this. For example, an add-in can have a page _that doesn't load Office.js_ open in a browser.

Comment: The route /action would contains an oob code inside the external link, therefore redirects the user to a reset password component where he can write down his new password

Comment: What exactly goes wrong if the link is opened in a normal web page? Is there an error?

Comment: Yes there is an error, the application is configured to be sideloaded as an addin only, you cannot open it as a normal web page anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way of doing this by sending a link to an SPA route to the user's email if the SPA always loads office.js; because you will get an error if you try to load office-js in a browser.

I suggest that your app send a **code** to the user's email and then have a place in UI of the add-in where the code can be typed in and submitted.

Alternatively, I'm not an expert on Angular, but perhaps there is a way to lazy load office.js only on the routes where it will actually be used. If so, then just don't load it on the /action route.

Comment: Two great ideas my good sir, many thanks. I will definitely try to make one of them work.